# При верстке сайта когда нужно использовать еm или %?

Tags: html, css

Привет.
При здании базового шрифта нужно использовать em или % и же можно обойтись в рх?
А остальные шрифты для каждого элемента?
Когда нужно использовать эти величины при верстке макета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**em** - ведут отсчет от базового размера шрифта браузера (16px), т.е. по умолчанию 1em = 16px.

**%** - та же история, что и с em. 100% = 16px;

Также можно обойтись и пикселями - отличная единица измерения, в основном пользуюсь ей. Вообще поищите, в google много чего на эту тему.

На сколько я помню, em используется для старых браузеров, в частности, для горячо всеми любимого IE, чтобы была возможность масштабировать текст. Новые браузеры это и с px умеют. В общем, пишите как Вам удобней, и будет Вам счастье.

Удачи

**P.s.** *Точно не помню..., базовый в браузерах 16px или 14px...*

Comment: а не будуть придираться если я буду использовать только рх?

Comment: Думаю, что придираться не будут. При адаптивной верстке, изменение размеров шрифта не частая процедура. В некоторых местах приходится поправить, но в основном размер остается базовым. - это что касается планшетов, нетбуков и т.д. 

Для телефонов и других мелких устройств, лучше написать отдельную таблицу стилей, так как с адаптивной, вы замучаетесь подгонять дизайн (был опыт...).